# Where would I add an IF statement to this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I need to add an IF statement that says: If item.decifld1=0 or NULL, consider it as 999999, otherwise simply use the value of item.decifld1 found.

**CODE**

```
SELECT
   job.whse
  ,SUM(CEILING((job.qty_released/item.decifld1))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_released
  ,SUM(CEILING((job.qty_complete/item.decifld1))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_complete
  ,SUM(CEILING(((job.qty_released-job.qty_complete)/item.decifld1))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_remaining
  ,SUM(job.qty_released) AS Sum_qty_released
  ,SUM(job.qty_complete) AS Sum_qty_complete
  ,SUM(job.qty_released-job.qty_complete) AS Sum_qty_remaining
FROM
  job
INNER JOIN
  item
ON
  job.item=item.item
WHERE
  job.job_date = @job_date
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'HK%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'HR%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'MMR%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'SS%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'SU%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'TR%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'WC%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'MN%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'QC%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'SC%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'CLN%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'NR%'  
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'WHS%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'Bill%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'PR%'
  AND job.job NOT LIKE 'WR%'
GROUP BY
  job.whse
```

Comment: In your Select statement

Comment: You could use [Case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: @ShreyasChavan is there a difference?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` do you use?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Difference between what ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan MS SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 if that helps

Comment: @ShreyasChavan whether to use `IF` or `CASE`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat `IF` and `CASE` are completely different things. IF  controls flow of query in a batch and CASE determines which value to use in a column of a select statement. In your case, `CASE` is the most appropriate.

Comment: Depending on the data type of item.decifld1 and other fields in the calulation, you might need to watch out for integer math.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(item.decifld1, 0), 999999)
```

instead of

```
item.decifld1
```

You can refer to the documentation of [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) and [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is not SQL.  It's procedural SQL, but in that case it's used for flow control and determining which queries to execute, not altering data values within a query.

Within a query, you want a CASE expression.

```
CASE 
    WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 999999 
    ELSE item.decifld1 
END
```

In your specific query:

```
SELECT
   job.whse
  ,SUM(CEILING((job.qty_released/CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 999999 ELSE item.decifld1 END))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_released
  ,SUM(CEILING((job.qty_complete/CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 999999 ELSE item.decifld1 END))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_complete
  ,SUM(CEILING(((job.qty_released-job.qty_complete)/CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 999999 ELSE item.decifld1 END))) AS Sum_pallet_qty_remaining
  ,SUM(job.qty_released) AS Sum_qty_released
  ,SUM(job.qty_complete) AS Sum_qty_complete
  ,SUM(job.qty_released-job.qty_complete) AS Sum_qty_remaining
FROM [...]
```

However, I'm guessing that what you're trying to do is make the division return zero when you can't divide.  If that's true, then what you probably actually want to do is this:

```
SELECT
     job.whse
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CEILING((job.qty_released/item.decifld1)) END) AS Sum_pallet_qty_released
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CEILING((job.qty_complete/item.decifld1)) END) AS Sum_pallet_qty_complete
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN item.decifld1 = 0 OR item.decifld1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CEILING(((job.qty_released-job.qty_complete)/item.decifld1)) END) AS Sum_pallet_qty_remaining
    [...]
```

In other words, if the denominator is `0` or `NULL`, then just treat the value of the whole division expression as `0`.  Otherwise, divide the values and take the ceiling.  Now you're not relying on the fact that `999999` is probably large enough to make the division and ceiling functions return a `0`, and instead explicitly telling the expression to behave in a certain way in certain circumstances.